# Using JavaScript, I want to replace this "TR>," with this "TR>"

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried using the replace function in js but I can't figure out the correct pattern for this. I keep getting the incorrect output.

```
t = "<TR><TD>Some Text</TD></TR>,<TR><TD>Some Text</TD></TR>,";

t = t.replace(/[TR\>\,]/g, "TR>");
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the `[]` class brackets

Comment: Can't get from the title what you need replaced.

Comment: You could do `t.replace(/<\/TR>/ig,'')` since closing TR tags are optional. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[]` defines a *character class*, which means "any of the characters within the `[...]`". You don't want that.

Simply remove them:

```
t = t.replace(/TR>,/g, "TR>");
```

You also don't need the backslashes before `>` or `,`, so I removed those too.

I'm not affiliated with it in any way, but I find https://regex101.com/#javascript quite handy when I'm working on JavaScript regexes.

Live example:

```js
var t = "<TR><TD>Some Text</TD></TR>,<TR><TD>Some Text</TD></TR>,";
snippet.log("Before: " + t);
t = t.replace(/TR>,/g, "TR>");
snippet.log("After: " + t);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
t = t.replace(/TR>,/g, "TR>");
```

Answer (score 1):

The square brackets, `[]`, are for matching any one of the characters inside them. So, your regex will match `T`, and `R`, and `>`, and `,`, instead of `TR>,` like you want. If you want to match the exact string, just use the string, `/TR>,/g`

```
t = t.replace(/TR>,/g, "TR>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
replace( /TR>,/g, "TR>" )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = "<TR><TD>Some Text</TD></TR>,<TR><TD>Some Text</TD></TR>,";
t = t.replace(/TR>,/mg, "TR>");
alert(t);
```

---

Outputs:

```
<TR><TD>Some Text</TD></TR><TR><TD>Some Text</TD></TR>
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/pJooNe)

---

**REGEX EXPLANATION**

```
Match the character string “TR>,” literally «TR>,»
Insert the character string “TR>” literally «TR>»
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this instead:

```js
t = "<TR><TD>Some Text</TD></TR>,<TR><TD>Some Text</TD></TR>,";

t = t.replace(/TR>,/g, "TR>");

alert(t)
```